# Layout to scroll above image view

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I want the layout to scroll above the image, its working fine but i need the image also to be clickable. How to achieve this ?

CODE :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/article_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                **android:paddingTop="150dp"**
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

                ...so may views...
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Since i have added `android:paddingTop="150dp"` the layout is scrolling above the image, but how will the image be clickable now ?

Comment: @PiotrGolinski in that case the ImageView will be on top and the Layout will be below that.

Comment: Did you close FrameLayout?

Comment: @AnshulTyagi Please see my code

Comment: So how should look your layout?

Comment: @PiotrGolinski  layout to scroll above the image, also the image to be clickable

Comment: if scrollview items will be over ImageView so how would you click it?

Comment: @user2056563 can you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

first try to add this beneath your existing frame layout in your xml file:

```
    <LinearLayout
    //set id here
    >
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/article_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    **android:paddingTop="150dp"**
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

                    ...so may views...
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

which is a copy of your layout but without frame layout which you will use when ever you need the image to be clickable.
then hide this grammatically in your `onCreate()`
then:
remove the frame layout programitaclly when ever you need the image to be clickable and make the copy of your layout visible, here is how to set your frame layout visibility to gone:
so define a frame layout as an instance of your class and set it to your frame layout id and when ever you need to make the image clickable add:

```
frmLayout.setVisibility(FrameLayout.GONE);
```

and

```
llLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please can you update your xml?  After you can click imageview easily.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/article_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

                    ...so may views...
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried your code this will fix the height of the Scroll view, image view should be ontop and scollview should scroll above the image view and fill the entire screen, i hope its clear.

Comment: @user2056563 ok i understand. 
This library help https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView

Answer (score 0):

try with relative parent and add you imageview just after the scroll view. Also give padding top to same size of your image height.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="250dp">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Hello" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/article_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/back" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think i missed to add framelayout here, but actually framelayout no needed any more